# Can I receive a warning when I fail to await a Promise in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, promise, async-await

TypeScript allows specifying the return type of functions:

```js
function delay(ms: number): Promise<void> {
    return new Promise( resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms) )
}
```

Somewhat frequently, I forget to await a function that returns a Promise:

```js
let waited = 0 
while (accessible === false && waited < MAX_DELAY) {
  waited += DELAY_MS
  delay(DELAY_MS) // oh no, this won't work correctly
  accessible = await this.dbAccessible()
}
```

TypeScript (`tsserver`) does warn me if I await an expression that *isn't* a promise

> 'await' has no effect on the type of this expression

Can I make `tsserver` (or something else, like a linter) warn me if I fail to await an expression that *is* a promise? I know this is sometimes valid (and I have used it), but it's less common in my experience than forgetting to await a promise that I meant to await.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use TSLint's [no-floating-promises](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-floating-promises/) rule, which enforces that

> [p]romises returned by functions must be handled appropriately.

More on the rule [here](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-floating-promises.md).